# What is "-n" in shell?

Tags: shell

For most of you it might be an easy question. However, I'm just new to shell scripting and somewhere I saw this:

```
#!/bin/sh
X=0
while [ -n "$X" ]
do
  echo "Enter some text (RETURN to quit)"
  read X
  echo "You said: $X"
done
```

I didn't understand what is -n here. I google, but couldn't find anything about -n. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: [string tests](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-n` is an argument to `[`, which is the name of command used here. Or actually an alias to the `test` command which additionally requires a matching `]` (which is an argument to `]` too - confusing, I know).

The [Wikipedia article on test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(Unix)) lists all its options, including `-n`:

> **-n** String1 - the length of the String1 variable is nonzero

Comment: You can also just simply check `man test` for options.